# Why does Uno.UI.Toolkit.VisibleBoundsPadding.PaddingMask="All" crash a UWP app occasionally?

Tags: uno-platform

I use [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) to target Windows, web, iOS, macOS, Android and Linux with a single code base. Uno.UI.Toolkit.VisibleBoundsPadding.PaddingMask="All" is used on almost every page of an app like the following:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="gridRoot"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    toolkit:VisibleBoundsPadding.PaddingMask="All"
    >
```

Occasionally, the UWP version crashes with the following exception:

```
Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Type: System.NullReferenceException
Stack trace:    at Uno.UI.Toolkit.VisibleBoundsPadding.VisibleBoundsDetails.UpdatePadding() + 0x8d
   at Uno.UI.Toolkit.VisibleBoundsPadding.VisibleBoundsDetails.<.ctor>b__5_0(ApplicationView, Object) + 0x8
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object, TEventArgs) + 0x2e
   at __Interop.Intrinsics.HasThisCall__51(Object, IntPtr, Object, Object) + 0x26
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x94ca05
```

It happens rarely (probably less than 0.1% of sessions), but it happens on different versions of Windows 10, so it is probably not related to the OS.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the handling of exceptional conditions (likely with Window.Current.Content). Can you open an issue with this ?

Comment: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/5274